# How to transfer google maps placemarks from my maps to iphone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to transfer the placemarks from google maps to iPhone maps. I usually set placemarks to the points of interest (sightseeings, hotels, restaurants) in foreign cities and using them with the iphone GPS would be great, however, I can't seem to find this functionality in the iphone app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions (neither very pretty.)

1. Make links to each location in Google Maps, then put them on a web page so that you can click onto them on your iPhone. (It's like a trip back to GeoCities!  And now "Geo" actually means something.)
2. Add each location to your address book, with a prefix to make it useful (I.E. "ROME - Interesting Cafe")

Neither of these methods are going to give you an overlay like you're really looking for, unfortunately.